# Passing session variables from an included session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a page, index.php, which includes another page, session.php. In session.php, I would like a session to start, and to set a session variable.

Upon running index.php, I would like the session variable set in session.php to be displayed.

I expected my code to work, but I have found that it does not.

index.php:

```
<?php

include "path/to/session.php";

echo $_SESSION['var'];

?>
```

session.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['var'] = "yes";


?>
```

I expected the output to be yes, and instead return no output.

EDIT:

I have tried this on Firefox and Chrome, to no discernible difference.

Upon inserting error handling as suggested below, it has not printed any errors.

Putting an echo "hi"; on session.php will output hi on index.php, so there's no obvious issue with the include or the pathing.

If I run session.php, having it echo the session_id(), the output will be the same each time I refresh the page; if I have the index.php echo the session_id(), it will not produce an output, and the output sent from session.php will be different each time I refresh the page, and does not appear to be reflective of session.php's session_id() when run from that page.

Comment: That should work -- have you confirmed that your sessions is actually getting set correctly?

Comment: They appear to print two different session_id() outputs, if that's what you're asking. How do I correct this?

Comment: Turn on error reporting - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/296555. See any errors or warnings?

Comment: No, turning on error reporting has not yielded any errors.

Comment: @cssstyleless, which editor do you use? Is it BOM free or not?

Comment: I am using Notepad++, encoding with UTF-8, which I am given to understand is the BOM-free option

Answer (score 0):

You have to include session_start() at the top of the index.php file

```
<?php
session_start();
include "path/to/session.php";

echo $_SESSION['var'];

?>
```